# How do I make parcel inline sourcemaps?

Tags: parceljs

By default parcel put source map in a separate file. How do I tell parcel to put source map in the same output file? I guess it is called inline source maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this section of the documentation: https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#sourcemap.

In your package.json, add the following:

```json
{
  "targets": {
    "default": {
      "sourceMap": {
        "inline": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you may need to change "default" to match your own target name, if you've configured other options.

Comment: It seems that this only works on production build, not on dev server

Answer (score 0):

Change your package.json and use " --no-source-maps" flag

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html --no-source-maps"
  },
```